# unable to send message from background script to content script in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I cannot send message from my background script to content script except i remove the popup.html from the browser action in the manifest.json. Someone help me

background.js

```
// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tabs) {
  // Send a message to the active tab
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {"message": "clicked_browser_action"});
  });
});

// This block is new! and will be used later
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if( request.message === "open_new_tab" ) {
      chrome.tabs.create({"url": request.url});
    }
  }
);
```

content.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if( request.message == "clicked_browser_action" ) {
   console.log("Congratulations you can now work!");
     
      // This line is new!
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"message": "open_new_tab", "url": firstHref});
    }
  }
);
```

manifest.json

```html
 {
    "name": "Wowprezi lead tool",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Extension to find leads and add to sales force!",
 "author": "Djouonang Landry",
    "manifest_version": 2,
 
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",

   "background": {
   "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"]
  },
  
   "content_scripts": [
        {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js","js/content.js"],
      "all_frames": true
        }
    ],
 
  
  "browser_action": {
   "default_popup": "html/popup.html",
   "default_title": "Find leads"
 }
 
}
```

popup.html - Except this is removed from the manifest.json i cannot send message from background to content.js. Please note i use the console function to check if the message was sent across to the content.js

Comment: Please post the code you are trying, as it stands we have nothing to go on here.

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked), the `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` listener is

> Fired when a browser action icon is clicked. **Does not fire if the
>   browser action has a popup.**

(bold type added).

Either remove the browserAction popup or move the code you currently have inside the listener to the popup page script.

Comment: nokonoko, i see your point but moving it to pop up will make the script shortlived since it runs as long as the pop up is alive and once closed it stops running.  I will need the process to continue even if the pop up is closed